# Exchange Web Services: Get a list of Rooms for a particular Time window

Tags: ios, exchangewebservices

In Exchange Web Services is there any way I can get a list of Rooms for a particular Time window.

I know that by using **getuseravailability** API I can check whether rooms are available for a time window. But my requirement is, I will pass a time window and I am expecting a list of Rooms (EmailIDs) that are available (free) for that particular time window.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a call like that. You would want to just add the rooms you're interested in to a `GetUserAvailability` call to see which ones are available.